# saved .pb file(created using darkflow) not loading in java

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, darknet, darkflow

I used the following command to create a .pb file:

```
flow --model ../YOLOv2/alexeyAB_darknet/darknet-master/cfg/yolov2-dppedestrian.cfg --load ../YOLOv2/alexeyAB_darknet/darknet-master/backup/yolov2-dppedestrian_33900.weights --savepb
```

Although the model was created successfully, when I load it into my java tensorflow application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: saved_model_cli
```

The problem is in the second line of code:

```
String model_path = "/home/adisys/Desktop/cloudiV2/models/yolo_pedestrian/saved_model";
SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(model_path, "serve");
```

I tried digging deep and found this link:
[Can not load pb file in tensorflow serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/491)
Following the link I ran the following command:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir saved_model/
```

The output is as follows:

> /home/adisys/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/init.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from float to np.floating is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type. from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>   The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:

As can be seen, there were no tag-sets displayed.
What could be the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your post, I'm sure the problem has solved itself now, but I'm leaving the comment for others working with darkflow. The command `--savepb` needs to be assigned as `--savepb True`